# In Eigen, how to combine multiple mapped matrices as an array of matrices

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a class that has multiple mapped matrices as members. The code is shown below:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(int nrow, int ncol, int nmat) : 
    arr(new int [nmat*nrow*ncol]),
    mat1(arr, nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic>(nrow * nmat, nmat)),
    mat2(arr + 1, nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic>(nrow * nmat, nmat)) {}

  int *arr;
  Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > mat1;
  Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > mat2;
};

int main()
{
  int nmat = 2;        // number of matrices
  int nrow = 3;        // number of rows for each matrix
  int ncol = 4;        // number of columns for each matrix
  int arr_size = nmat*nrow*ncol; // size of the array.

  MyClass A (nrow, ncol, nmat);
  for (int i=0; i<arr_size; i++) {
    A.arr[i] = i+1;
  }

  cout <<"mat1 = \n"<<A.mat1<<endl;
  cout <<"mat2 = \n"<<A.mat2<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Now I want to make `mat1` and `mat2` be an array of two matrics, as `mat[0]` and `mat[1]`. I was trying to do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(int nrow, int ncol, int nmat) : 
    arr(new int [nmat*nrow*ncol]),
    mat[0](arr, nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic>(nrow * nmat, nmat)),
    mat[1](arr + 1, nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic>(nrow * nmat, nmat)) {}

  int *arr;
  Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > mat[2];
};
```

It obviously doesn't work, since I cant do this in the initializer list. But to do this kind of mapping with stride, I have to use initializer list. Anyone has an idea on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++11 you can do this

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(int* arr, int nrow, int ncol, int nmat) :
      mat { { arr, nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic>(nrow * nmat, nmat) },
            { arr + 1, nrow, ncol, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic>(nrow * nmat, nmat) } } {
    std::cout << mat[1].data() - arr << std::endl;
    std::cout << mat[1].rows() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mat[1].cols() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mat[1].innerStride() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mat[1].outerStride() << std::endl;
  }

  Map<MatrixXi, 0, Stride<Dynamic, Dynamic> > mat[2];
};
```

It should be case 5 of the list initialization in the following link.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

On the other hand, `Eigen::Map` is just a light-weight wrapper to the raw pointers and dimensions. You may want to put `arr`, `nrow`, `ncol` and `nmat` as class members and construct `Eigen::Map` on the fly.

Comment: I tried this and got " `error: bad array initializer` ". Could that be a compiler issue? I use g++ 4.4.7 with the flag `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: it is too old. try at least 4.9

Comment: thanks, I will try it once our computer system administrative make the newer version of `gcc` available today. A follow up question would be, what if I want the number of matrices to be `nmat` instead of `2`? Is there a way to introduce a `for` loop in the initializer list?

Comment: No way. Constructing Map on the fly will be better.

Comment: I have tested it using gcc 4.9.2 and it is working. Thanks!